# Rank top 3 columns in excel with highest number of value among 5 columns using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to filter top three columns with value '1' among four columns. i.e I wish to know top three columns which have highest number of '1'. Date set is as following:

[image: Date set representation]

Comment: And which part of this task are you having problems with?  (Your question doesn't make it clear.)

Comment: Purpose is to find from columns X1,X2,X3,X4 which columns  have  most number of '1', arranged in rank of top three

Comment: You are looking for the [WorksheetFunction.SumIf Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195946.aspx). If you need further help show the code you already have and ask a specific question to your code.

Comment: I don't want the sum of values in these columns

Comment: But you will need to calculate the sum of `1s` (ones) you have in each column to know how many `1` are in each column and then you can determine which column has the top most 1s, second most 1s and so on. Alternatively have a look at [WorksheetFunction.CountIf Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839272.aspx) if this is more logical to you (both will work).

Comment: thank you , I didn't look at it that way